# two relations "has one" referencing to the same table - Kohana 3.1 ORM

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I have table `messages` with two foreign key: `user_id_from` and `user_id_to`.
I need to retrieve both rows from table `users` with "has one" relation.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed this is actually a belongs to relationship. So the code should be as follows...

```
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'user_from' => array('model' => 'user', 'foreign_key' => 'user_id_from'),
    'user_to' => array('model' => 'user', 'foreign_key' => 'user_id_to')
);
```

The user_from and user_to can be changed to however you want to access them.

i.e.

```
$message->user_from
```

and

```
$message->user_to
```